# Why assuming singleton elimination and definitional proof irrelevance leads to UIP, in Coq?

Tags: coq, homotopy-type-theory

I was reading the paper [Definitional proof-irrelevance without K](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3290316), which states, in page 3, that

> If proof irrelevance holds for the equality type, every equality has at most one proof, which is known as Uniqueness of Identity Proofs (UIP). Therefore, assuming proof irrelevance together with the singleton elimination enforces a new axiom in the theory, which is for instance incompatible with the univalence axiom from HoTT.

I do not understand the implication, as I do not understand the role of the elimination here. For me, once we have definitional proof irrelevance, applied to `eq`, it gives us K. The only way to escape K is to prevent definitional proof irrelevance in `eq`. Where am I wrong?

Comment: They might be making a distinction between (in Coq terms) defining `eq` in `Prop` and `eq` in `Type`. To go from the latter to the former, you need singleton elimination. And if you do not have that, `eq` in `Type` might not be affected by proof irrelevance.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, @JoJoModding I think that the distinction is between `SProp`, which is proof-irrelevant, and `Prop`, which is not. `SProp` does not add proof irrelevance to Coq because `eq` is defined in `Prop`. I think the idea is that if we defined an `eq'` in `SProp` and we had singleton elimination, we could eliminate proofs of `eq'` to proofs of `eq`, propagating the proof irrelevance. However, I could not complete this proof Insights?